# ModuleNotFoundError when attempting runserver in a new Django project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

**Description:**

I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError while trying to run a developer server in a new Django project with a fresh virtual environment. The error refers to a project named "Carshering" and boostrap import that has no connection to the current project which is just created empty template. I'd like to understand the reason behind this error and how to resolve it. The error message includes `<frozen importlib._bootstrap>`, which prompted me to install two        Bootstrap-related modules.

```
(venv) C:\Users\karpi\PycharmProjects\WEB_QUIZ>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karpi\PycharmProjects\WEB_QUIZ\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Carshering'
```

*During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karpi\PycharmProjects\WEB_QUIZ\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Carshering'
```

**Expected Outcome:**

I expect the server to run successfully without any ModuleNotFoundError related to the "Carshering" project.

**Attempts so far:**

- Created a new Django project in a fresh virtual environment.
- Installed Bootstrap using pip.
- Checked the installed packages and verified that the virtual environment is activated.
- Tried running the migration using the command python manage.py makemigrations, but encountered the ModuleNotFoundError.
- set PYTHONPATH

**Additional Information:**

- Django version: 4.2.3
- Python version: 3.11
- django-bootstrap-form 3.4*
- crispy-bootstrap5 0.7*

*These installations were attempted in hopes of resolving the issue.

Comment: Without seeing your **settings.py**, and perhaps other code it's impossible to know why you get the error you show.  It could be as simple as not including `Carshering` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the **settings.py** file.

Comment: It's just a default **settings.py** generated after creating django project template with an app named ```quiz``` in project ```sdaquiz```. ```Carshering``` is just another project on my PC not related to new project I'm trying to run.

Comment: OK, but after you add an app to your project, you still have to add it to the default `INSTALLED_APPS` to your **settings.py**.  The default **settings.py** does NOT include any apps you add.

Comment: I already did this.

Comment: Understood.  But without seeing more of your code, I can't troubleshoot.  This is a common error with many possible causes.  Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after installing this app, assuming it has any classes in its **models.py**.  Is it included in **settings.py** `INSTALLED_APPS`?  Maybe I'm  not seeing something more obvious, but it's tough to troubleshout given what you have written.

Comment: I followed these steps:
```django-admin startproject sdaquiz .```
```python manage.py startapp quiz```
Add quiz to ```INSTALLED_APPS``` and got mentioned error after trying to
```python manage.py runserver/makemigrations/createsuperuser```
In the very first attempt to see if I can run developer server.

Comment: You say you created a fresh django project in a ne w virtual environment, but you still get an error.  Is `Carshering` anywhere in you rcode?  Again, without seeing more of your  code, it's just guessing.

Comment: Yes, fresh django project template with only ```'quiz'``` added to ```INSTALLED_APPS```

Comment: Again, I don't see your code, I don't see where `Carshering` appears in your code.  I think maybe someone else can help because clearly, I don't have enough information to help.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance in trying to resolve the issue. Fortunately, I managed to solve it by removing the ```pythonpath``` associated with the ```carshering``` project from the system environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue. After removing `PYTHONPATH` with `Carshering` and `carshering.settings` from the system environment variables, the issue has been resolved.